# How to get ng-content before rendering in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to get the html code written inside a component's selector tags as it is (before rendering to the browser). For example assume my components are parent and child,

in child,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
...
```

in parent,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <child>
            <p>Title 1</p>
            <some-other-component [input]="1"></some-other-component>
        </child>


        <child>
            <p>Title 2</p>
            <some-other-component [input]="2"></some-other-component>
        </child>
    `
})
...
```

In the child component I need the html code written inside  tags as a string. i.e. in the above scenario, I need `"<p>Title 1</p> <some-other-component [input]="1"></some-other-component>"` and `"<p>Title 2</p> <some-other-component [input]="2"></some-other-component>"`.

P.S. My objective here is to create a code snippet page, where I can pass html code snippet as ng-content which will be used to render both preview and code sample.

Answer (score -2):

You can add unique classes to your content parts and select then using next component configuration. Selector here is any valid `querySelector` fn selector

```
<ng-content select=".first">
```

and

```
<ng-content select=".second">
```

So your content can be like this

```
    <child class="fisrt">
        <p>Title 1</p>
        <some-other-component [input]="1"></some-other-component>
    </child>


    <child class="second">
        <p>Title 2</p>
        <some-other-component [input]="2"></some-other-component>
    </child>
```